# RelayJS: How to set initialVariables via props

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql, graphql-js

Lets say I have a GraphQL type `Echo` that echo whatever I query with some decorations. On the other hand, I have a React component that echo `message` passed to it with some decorations determined by `Echo` type. How can I set `initialVariables` for the `Echo` component?

I read that setting props sets `initialVariables`, however that does not work. I have tried `componentDidMount`, but that does not work too.

This [Relay Playground](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=class%20Echo%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20componentDidMount()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20%7Brelay%2C%20message%7D%20%3D%20this.props%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20relay.setVariables(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20message%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20name%20%3D%20''%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(this.props.echo)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%20%3D%20this.props.echo.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EMessage%3A%20%7Bname%7D%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AEcho%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(Echo%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20message%3A%20null%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20echo%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Echo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name(message%3A%20%24message)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20EchoApp%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEcho%20echo%3D%7Bthis.props.viewer.echo%7D%20message%3D%22Test%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AEchoApp%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(EchoApp%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20echo%20%7B%20%24%7BEcho.getFragment('echo')%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20EchoRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'Home'%3B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20(Component)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%20%7B%20%24%7BComponent.getFragment('viewer')%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BEchoApp%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20EchoRoute()%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B&schema=import%20%7B%0A%20%20GraphQLObjectType%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLSchema%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql'%3B%0A%0Alet%20EchoType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Echo'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(echo%2C%20%7Bmessage%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%60Hello%2C%20%24%7Bmessage%7D!%60%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0Alet%20ViewerType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Viewer'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20echo%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20EchoType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0Aexport%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema(%7B%0A%20%20query%3A%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Query'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20ViewerType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A) shows that message is not being displayed correctly.

For context,

```jsx
// This component consumes `Echo` type
class Echo extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let {relay, message} = this.props; 

    relay.setVariables({
      message
    });
  }

  render() {
    let name = '';
    if (this.props.echo) {
      name = this.props.echo.name;
    }

    return (
      <li>Message: {name}</li>
    );
  }
}

Echo = Relay.createContainer(Echo, {
  // By default `message` is null
  initialVariables: {
    message: null
  },

  fragments: {
    echo: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Echo {
        name(message: $message)
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

This is the type that resolve with an echo

```js
let EchoType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Echo',
  fields: () => ({
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      args: {
        message: {
          type: GraphQLString
        }
      },
      resolve: (echo, {message}) => `Hello, ${message}!`
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll admit I don't know a whole lot about Relay, but the `message` property passed to `Echo` seems to be shadowing it (or otherwise affecting it). I made the following changes:

1. Change the prop name passed to `Echo`:

   ```js
   <Echo echo={this.props.viewer.echo} defaultMessage="Default"/>
   ```
2. Change the property name in `componentDidMount`:

   ```js
   componentDidMount() {
     let {relay, defaultMessage} = this.props; 

     relay.setVariables({
       message: defaultMessage
     });
   }
   ```

Here is the full source (and [a link to a working example](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=class%20Echo%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20componentDidMount()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20%7Brelay%2C%20defaultMessage%7D%20%3D%20this.props%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20relay.setVariables(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20message%3A%20defaultMessage%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20name%20%3D%20''%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(this.props.echo)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%20%3D%20this.props.echo.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EMessage%3A%20%7Bname%7D%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AEcho%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(Echo%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20initialVariables%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20message%3A%20%22%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20echo%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Echo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name(message%3A%20%24message)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20EchoApp%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEcho%20echo%3D%7Bthis.props.viewer.echo%7D%20defaultMessage%3D%22Default%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AEchoApp%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(EchoApp%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Viewer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20echo%20%7B%20%24%7BEcho.getFragment('echo')%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aclass%20EchoRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'Home'%3B%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20(Component)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%20%7B%20%24%7BComponent.getFragment('viewer')%7D%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BEchoApp%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20EchoRoute()%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B&schema=import%20%7B%0A%20%20GraphQLObjectType%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLSchema%2C%0A%20%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%7D%20from%20'graphql'%3B%0A%0Alet%20EchoType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Echo'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20args%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20GraphQLString%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20(echo%2C%20%7Bmessage%7D)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(message)%20%7C%7C%20%60Hello%2C%20%24%7Bmessage%7D!%60%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0Alet%20ViewerType%20%3D%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Viewer'%2C%0A%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20echo%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20EchoType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0Aexport%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema(%7B%0A%20%20query%3A%20new%20GraphQLObjectType(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'Query'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20fields%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20viewer%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20ViewerType%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A)):

```js
class Echo extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let {relay, defaultMessage} = this.props; 

    relay.setVariables({
      message: defaultMessage
    });
  }

  render() {
    let name = '';
    if (this.props.echo) {
      name = this.props.echo.name;
    }

    return (
      <li>Message: {name}</li>
    );
  }
}
Echo = Relay.createContainer(Echo, {
  initialVariables: {
    message: ""
  },
  fragments: {
    echo: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Echo {
        name(message: $message)
      }
    `,
  },
});

class EchoApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ul>
      <Echo echo={this.props.viewer.echo} defaultMessage="Default"/>
    </ul>;
  }
}
EchoApp = Relay.createContainer(EchoApp, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        echo { ${Echo.getFragment('echo')} },
      }
    `,
  },
});

class EchoRoute extends Relay.Route {
  static routeName = 'Home';
  static queries = {
    viewer: (Component) => Relay.QL`
      query {
        viewer { ${Component.getFragment('viewer')} },
      }
    `,
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Relay.RootContainer
    Component={EchoApp}
    route={new EchoRoute()}
  />,
  mountNode
);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted! It feels like a workaround of what Relay is missing anyway :)

Comment: Thank you! This is an absolute farce. I thought the whole point was that you passed the variables to set as props, not that you had to pass slightly differently named props and set them yourself (you're right, there's some sort of shadowing going on). I've wasted hours on this :-(

Comment: @jbrown I thought that too — and what makes even less sense is that if you do it like that, I can see that `this.props.relay.variables.message` is the prop that's passed into the component, and yet the component doesn't display the data I expect; `this.props.echo` is undefined.

Comment: @MichelleTilley Yeah that was the part that was confusing me most.